# How can I remove two labels from my legend with an alternative to item.datasetIndex !== 1 && item.datasetIndex !== 4; ? (Charts.js)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Hey guys I was trying to remove two labels from my legend. I tried dozens of things but I cannot find a way to make it work. Hope you can see the error here and why I cannot get rid of two labels in my legend? As you can see I tried to use item.datasetIndex !== 1 && item.datasetIndex !== 4; However it did not change anything

```
const decimals = 0;


myData = {
        labels: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9+'],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "25th Percentile",
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: '#645bff',
            pointBackgroundColor: "#645bff",
            borderColor: '#645bff',
            data: [28, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 62, 66, 70, 78],
            borderWidth:1,
            pointRadius: 0,
            pointBorderWidth: 3,
            pointHoverRadius: 3,
            pointHitRadius: 3},
            
          {
            label: "10th - 90th Percentile",
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: '#c4c1ff',
            pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
            borderColor: '#c4c1ff',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
            data: [40, 65, 63, 64, 72, 79, 83, 87, 100,108],
            borderWidth: 1,
            pointRadius: 0,
            pointBorderWidth: 3,
            pointHoverRadius: 3,
            pointHitRadius: 3},
          
          {
            label: "Median",
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: '#0d0e25',
            pointBackgroundColor: "#0d0e25",
            borderColor: '#0d0e25',
            data: [30, 40, 45, 50, 56, 60, 66, 73, 78, 85],
            borderWidth:1,
            pointRadius:2,
            pointBorderWidth: 3,
            pointHoverRadius: 3,
            pointHitRadius: 3},
          
          {
            label: "25th-75th Percentile",
            showInLegend: false,
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: '#645bff',
            pointBackgroundColor: "#645bff",
            borderColor: '#645bff',
            data: [35, 50, 51, 55, 63, 69, 73, 80, 85, 94],
            borderWidth:1,
            pointRadius: 0,
            pointBorderWidth: 3,
            pointHoverRadius: 3,
            pointHitRadius: 3},
          {
            label: "10th Percentile",
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: '#c4c1ff',
            pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
            borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
            pointStyle: "circle",
            borderColor: '#c4c1ff',
            data: [25, 30, 36, 39, 45, 49, 53, 56, 60, 68],
            borderWidth:1,
            hoverRadius: 9,
            pointRadius: 0,
            pointBorderWidth: 3,
            pointHoverRadius: 3,
            pointHitRadius: 3,},
          
       ]
    };

// Default chart defined with type: 'line'
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart2 = new Chart(ctx, {type: 'line',data: myData,

options: {legend: {onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation(),
        display: true,
        labels: {
          filter: function(item,
            myChart) {
          return item.datasetIndex !== 1 && item.datasetIndex !== 4;
          }
        }
      },title:{display:true,text: 'Frontend Engineer salaries (757 datapoints)'},plugins: {filler: {propagate: false}}, scales: 
            
{xAxes:[{gridLines: {drawOnChartArea:false},ticks:{beginAtZero: true,stepSize:20,},scaleLabel: {display: true,labelString: 'Years of relevant experience',fontSize: 20}}],
                                                           yAxes: [{id: 'a',type: 'linear',position:'left',gridLines: {drawOnChartArea:false},scaleLabel: {display:true,labelString: 'Salary',fontSize: 20},
ticks: {beginAtZero: true,stepSize: 20,callback:function(value, index,values) 
                                                           {return '$' + value.toFixed(decimals)}}}, 
                                                           {id: 'b',type: 'linear',position: 'right',ticks: {display: false},gridLines: {lineWidth:0.5},scaleLabel: {display: false},ticks: {display: false,beginAtZero: true,stepSize: 20}}]
 }},
 tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
          label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
            if (label) {
              label += ': ';
            }
            if (label === "25th-75th Percentile: ") {
              label = "75th Percentile: "
            }
            if (label === "10th - 90th Percentile: ") {
              label = "90th Percentile: "
              }
            label += tooltipItem.yLabel
            return label;
            
          }
        }
      },
           
           
           
           
           



})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your return line in the labels filter function to this: `return !(item.datasetIndex === 1 || item.datasetIndex === 4)` then it will work

EDIT:
To get your original way to work you can just put parentheses around it, will work too: `return (item.datasetIndex !== 1 && item.datasetIndex !== 4)`

Comment: Maybe my HTML Block is important to see the mistake. I have a dropdown menu.:<div class="container">
  <div class = "title">
    <h1>Chart.js Fun</h1>
    <h3>Try to update the chart type and randomize the data!</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <h5 class="label">Chart Type</h5>
    <select name="chartType" id="chartType" onchange="updateChartType()">
      <option value="line">Frontend Engineer</option>
    </select>
    
  </div>
  <div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; width:85vw">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>    
</div>